# I want to render different course/name page for different value of names

Tags: node.js, express, routes, ejs

```
const express= require('express');
const app = express();
const path =require('path');

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.get('/',(req, res)=>{
    res.sendFile(`${__dirname}/index.html`)
})

app.get('/Course/:name',(req,res)=>{
   const {name} = req.params;
   console.log({name});
   res.render({name});
})
app.listen(3000,()=>{
    console.log('server up')})
```

**like if the url is https://example.com/Course/web it should render Course\web.ejs file **

Comment: why don't you do something like this you have one `course.ejs` file and just pass the name of `course` and load data according to that

Comment: this is **bad practice** to render different file for different request. **Imagine you have thousands of course** then you have to make thousands of `html` files so instead you can make one file and load data dynamically according to name of course